# Как сделать выпадающее меню на php?

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

Всем привет! Как сделать чтобы при нажатии мыши на слово открывалось следующее подменю?
Имеется сайта на WordPress. Через конструктор ничего не редактируется, только какие-то основные моменты. Нашел файл sidebar.php с кодом. Я так понимаю, что нужно именно здесь и редактировать

```
 <aside class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <?php foreach( get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0)) as $category ): ?>
            <li class="sidebar-menu__item">
                <a href="<?= get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ?>" class="sidebar-menu__link arrow arrow_right"><?= $category->name ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

В интернете порылся и ничего не нашел подходящего.
Сам в php не шарю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел файл с надписью sidebar.less. Других подходящих нет
Получается нужно редактировать в этом файле?

```
.sidebar {
  //flex: 0 0 260px;
  //max-width: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid @primary;
  border-top: none;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  &__item {
    font-size: .93em;
    position: relative;
    &::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 1.43em;
      right: 1.4em;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    &:first-child::after {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  &__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.13rem 1.13rem 1.13rem 2.6rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover {
      color: @primary;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Скрин файлов less]

Comment: Всякие интерактивные вещи, по типу выпадающих меню и тому подобного, не имеют особого отношения к PHP и как правило делаются при помощи CSS/JS. В приведенном Вами коде просто выводится разметка в которой списком с ссылками выводятся категории в сайдбаре (боковая панель), как можно заметить по названию файла который Вы редактировали.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Для начала, опишите что Вы собрались редактировать и чтобы что? Если Вы отредактируете LESS файл, это ничего не даст, так как он должен быть скомпилирован в CSS и сам по себе он работать не будет. Если Вы не являетесь разработчиком, то лучшее вообще не трогать файлы. К тому же перед раедактированием какого либо файла темы, сделать дочернюю тему и редактировать файлы только в дочерней теме, иначе при следующем обновлении темы, все Ваши правки слетят.

Comment: Если посмотреть на одну из [демок](https://themes.g5plus.net/orion/creative-business/) темы которой Вы пользуетесь, там есть меню с дропдауном, вид у него конечно не такой как Вам нужен, но судя по вопросам которые Вы задаете, ничем хорошим это не закончится, только время потеряете.

Comment: Тема сайта самописная, как мне говорили. Я думал, что в файле sidebar.less просто необходимо добавить какую-нибудь переменную и все будет нормально) Так то мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на, допустим, Алкотестеры выпадало еще подменю с двумя Названиями, допустим, Производственные и Личные. А через конструктор этого не возможно сделать. При открытие в конструкторе этого меню вообще нет.

Comment: Хорошо, тема возможно и самописная, просто название совпадает с одной из премиальных. Это так не работает, что просто добавил переменную и все заработало :) По идее Вам просто нужно перейти в Внешний вид -> Меню и просто добавить два дочерних пункта к нужному пункту меню. Если разработчики это предусмотрели, то там будет выпадающий список.